# SQL Server CE Database: SSMS Remembers My Password, But I Don't -- Next Steps?

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

Good morning all,

I created a database in SQL Server Compact Edition using SQL Server Management Studio.  When I started, I created a password and had SSMS remember it for me.  However, I'm reaching the point when I pass the database on to others... and it suddenly hit me: I *forgot* my password.

Does anybody know what recourse I may have in this situation?  Is there a way to recover the password, or to replicate the database (from within SSMS) to a new, password-free copy?  I suppose as an absolute last resort -- the project is reasonably small, only a couple dozen tables -- I could export everything to text files and re-create it from scratch.  Is there functionality within SSMS/SQLCE, or are there third-party tools, to make that task a little easier?

Thank you very much for your time and advice.

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

You can install my SSMS add-in which allows you to export the entire database to a script file, that you can then run against a new database - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you very much ErikEJ.  It looks like the tool is free of cost, but may require admin privileges on the computer?  Of course, it's a simple request to IT, but it will require that I admit I forgot my password. :)

Comment: You can also use the command line tool (same site) - exportsqlce.exe - requires no admin rights

Comment: Thank you very much Erik.  I also found your [detector](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=47e59e4beb70472b&sc=documents&id=47E59E4BEB70472B%21299) to tell me what version of SQLCE I had.  But my problem is that I don't know remember the password I set for the database! (oops) ...so I am stuck with using SSMS, which remembers it for now.  Can ExportSqlCE get around that?  <stupidly hopeful look>

Comment: No, in that case you must install the add-in.